Supabase One to Many Relationship with multiple tables
I have a scenario when I have 3 entities, namely, user, team, and school, which all have an account.
After some research, I learned that this can be represented as polymorphic association. I am still new to Supabase and not sure how it implemented this using the ui, and my sql is a bit rusty.
Any direction or guidance will be appreciated.
